# Вопрос о String в Java\C#

Tags: c#, java, строки

Скажите есть ли разница между кодом:

- `String st = "Hello";`
- `String st = new String("Hello");`

В любом же случае я получаю объект `st`!

Comment: насчет Java не знаю, а в C# разница есть. В C# вторая строка не скомпилируется в отличие от первой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для java разница в производительности.
Вторая строка будет работать дольше.
Причина в том что первая строка будет аналогична вызову valueOf метода, который использует кеш, а вот вторя строка конструирует новый объект без кеша.

Проверить можно так

```
String str1 = new String("java");
String str2 = new String("java");
if(str1 == str2)  // returns false
if(str1.equals(str2)) // returns true
```

тут кеша нет.

А тут есть:

```
String str1 = "java";
String str2 = "java";
if(str1 == str2)  // returns true
if(str1.equals(str2)) // returns true
```

Comment: @ICE Большое спасибо ...